# PyroCMS: How to include one page inside another

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a site with an "About us" page which is divided into multiple sections.

```
About Us
    +Overview
    +The Company
    +Our services
    +Future plans
    (etc)
```

I want to have a floated block on the right hand side of each of these pages which contains links to every other page.

Ideally, what I would like is to create a page titled AboutUsSidebar, and then be able to include this page in all of the about sections through some kind of tag, ie..

```
{include('Sidebar')}
```

Is there anything like this in PyroCMS? Or perhaps a better way to do it?

Comment: Where do I put that? You realise this is question about PyroCms and not CodeIgniter itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I was able to achieve the desired result by using a page type.

I have a page type called "About" which contains the sidebar html, then I use pages on top of that page  type for each of the sections.

Worked very nicely.

Comment: can you write in comment the tag you have used please? I want to do the same thing . Thanks

Comment: I didn't find a tag. Create a page type instead. Login to admin, go to content -> pages -> page types. Create a new page type containing your base template (put {{ body }} tag somewhere in it). Now create a page which uses your new page type. It's like template inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use view partials.

Create your sidebar with it's HTML and save it into addons/shared_addons/themes/yourtheme/views/partials/sidebar.html and then you can include it in your layouts as so:

```
{{ theme:partial name="sidebar" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like page types are the way to go, I didn't see the page types button at the top of the page before.